# iOS 7.1 animation bug

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

Yesterday I updated my **iPhone 5 to iOS 7.1** and found a strange bug in my current application. There is few `UINavigationControllers`. After few transition in it the animation of transition become to fast, like there is no animation at all. But more strange that all system animation became to fast, default **UITableCell** animation, modal window animation and so on.

Does someone know what is this? On device with 7.0.6 there is no such problem.

Looks like it starts to happen after few calls of:
[navController setViewControllers:popViewControllers animated:animated];

PS: One more thing - my app is still using **iOS 6.1 SDK**.

PPS: i don't use custom default animations.

UPDATE: With 7.1 SDK problem still exists.

Comment: Try to build with the latest SDK (7.1). This may solve your problem.

Comment: Apple no longer accepts app submissions with any SDK lower than 7 and build with xcode 5. You will need to update your Xcode and SDK.

Comment: I tried to build it with 7.1 but bug is still exists. So problem is not in SDK.

Comment: @Eugene Can you please post a video of the problem, and possibly a demo project reproducing the issue?

Comment: code ? how are you presenting the controllers/manually popping any ?

Comment: Thank you everybody. Problem solved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have similar problem after updating my iPhone from iOS 7.0.3 to 7.1. I go back and forth several times using the navigation bar and after a few tries there is no transition animation. All animations are broken when it happens, eg. device rotation animation. After reaching this state, few more back and forth transitions cause a crash.

Edit 3:

In my case the problem was because of accessing GUI objects from a background queue. If you experience this issue make sure all GUI objects are accessed from the main thread. Many thanks to Eugene for helping me figure this out.

Comment: I found that SDWebImage manager updates image not in main thread!

Comment: Many thanks for sharing that. In my app I make snapshots of views and it happens also in background thread. Hadn't chance to check it yet but I am quite sure it will help to switch that activity to the main thread